# How to implement interactive transitions in a custom container view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, containers, transition, interactive

I implemented my own custom container view controller and I try to make it compatible with iOS 7 view controller transitions. I make my custom container view controller conform to `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` and I send `self` when I call `transitionDuration:` and `animateTransition:`. It all works fine as long as I use only animated transitions.

Now I want to make it work with interactive transitions, so I call the interaction controller's `startInteractiveTransition:` instead of the animation controller's `animateTransition:`, using `self` again as a parameter. However, if I use a `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` as the interaction controller, it then calls a `_animator` method on my context (which is the container view controller itself). Of course, I haven't implemented this method which is private and undocumented, so it crashes...

Am I missing something in my implementation? Is `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` only compatible with Apple classes because it uses some implementation magic (as when it requires that everything should be in a `UIView` animation block)? The documentation and header files make it look like we can implement our own container view controllers and still use custom transitions, but is it really true or just wishful thinking because nobody would actually do that?

If I can't use `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, then where exactly should the interaction/animation logic be? In the `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext` object? In the `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` object (most likely, this object is the driver...)? Or in the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` object (this is probably where the real animation should happen, but would that mean calling `animateTransition:` several times during the interaction? Or adding new methods for each step of the interactive transition?)

Edit: The documentation says:

> A percent-driven interactive transition object drives the custom animation between the disappearance of one view controller and the appearance of another. It relies on a transition animator delegate—a custom object that adopts the `UIViewControllerAnimatorTransitioning` protocol—to set up and perform the animations.

There is no `UIViewControllerAnimatorTransitioning` protocol. Assuming it is a mistake, or a name change that happened during iOS 7 development and it is actually the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol, how do we link the interaction controller with the animation controller? I guess it's the responsibility of the view controller driving the transition but I don't see any API to make this link, so it would mean that `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` is indeed reserved for Apple classes?

Comment: I ended up writing my own interactive transition from scratch, as implied in the other comments below, I don't use UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.

Comment: Could you explain how you made your custom container compatible with the new iOS7 transitioning API ? I'm currently trying to do the same. Problem is, i don't know which methods to call or which protocols to conform to to make this work. I'm pretty familiar with the API itself for the 'common' use cases (presentViewController, custom navigationController transition), though.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out myself. It's very easy actually. Thanks for your post :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same on my own and ended up writing my own `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` equivalent. Seems like the percent driven transition asks for the animation and actually starts it after the interactive transition is started. I've got some trouble with implementing the reverse animation when canceling though.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing too. For the cancellation, I play a animation symmetrical to what happened already up to the cancellation. The tricky part is to rebuild the correct view controllers hierarchy in the container and call again all the `willMoveToParentViewController:` family callbacks. Also it results in my case in unbalanced calls to `beginAppearanceTransition:` / `endAppearanceTransition`... And animating a navigation bar in parallel to the interactive transition is yet another piece of work!

Comment: Depending on the nature of your container view controller, you don't always need to call the `willMoveToParentViewController`callbacks when transitioning. `UITabBarController` for instance, makes those calls in `viewDidLoad`, but not when changing tabs. How did you play those symmetrical cancel animations? By copying all the animations in the layer, removing them and then re-adding the copies?

Comment: I don't know by which magic the percent driven interactive transaction really works. I implemented my own interactive transition, where I move things around depending on the percentComplete parameter. Then if I finish the transition, I start an animation from the current value of percentComplete to 1. If I cancel the transition, I start an animation from the current value of percentComplete to 0. There is nothing really difficult, but a lot of writing.