# Custom Containers and Custom Transitions

Tags: ios, ios7

Custom transitions work easily with standard containers and while presenting modal view controllers. But what about using custom transitions with a totally custom container?

I'd like to use the `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` protocol with my custom container and take advantage of transitioning and interactive transitions.

In the comment into the header file of `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` I read:

```
// The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol can be adopted by custom
// container controllers.  It is purposely general to cover more complex
// transitions than the system currently supports.
```

but I can't understand how to create a Context Transitioning and start all the custom transition process.

Comment: Did you try calling presentViewController:animated:completion: and addChildViewController: together within pushing view controller method of your custom container class? I couldn't find any method other than presentViewController which causes a call to transition delegate.

Comment: So do you think that just presentViewController do the trick? 
I thought about this function just as related to modal view controller... but probably you're right.

Comment: If you have time to try it out, please tell if it works, I've been a too busy to try right now.

Comment: I'll do for sure in the next days... please take a look a this question and eventually fill an answer with your comment so that I can accept it :)

Comment: I'm very sorry, buddy :( I tried every way I could come up with but no use. At last, I looked up at that header file and I read "For now..." part, then I gave up. But thanks for your great question, I learnt many things while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very well possible!

have a look at this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384949/how-to-implement-interactive-transitions-in-a-custom-container-view-controller?rq=1).

You just have to create a viewController conforming to the UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol and use the ViewController Containment API (addChildViewController:, willMoveToParentViewController:, and so on).

When you want to start the custom transition, simply call the [animateTransition] Method on your transitionController. From that point on, it's the same as with the Apple-provided API.

Make your custom container fit in with the Transitioning API.

In fact, all the new protocols introduced in iOS7 (UIViewControllerContextTransitioning and so on) are not really needed to implement your own fully custom containerViewController. Its just providing a neat class-relationship and method pool. But you could write that all by yourself and would not need to use any private API.
ViewController Containment (introduced in iOS5) is all you need for this job.

I just tried gave it a try and its even working with interactive transitions.

If you need some sample code please let me know and i'll provide some :)

**EDIT**

By the way, this is how Facebook and Instagram for iOS is creating their navigation concept. You can scroll away the NavigationBar in these Apps and when a new ViewController is "pushed" the NavigationBar seems to have been reset during the pushing.

Ironically, i asked the exact same question a month ago here on StackOverflow :D

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641464/ios7-facebook-navigationbar-behavior)

And I just realized i answered it myself :)

Have a nice day !

Comment: I've accepted your answer! this is the right one :) thank you! It would be great to have some code examples. At the moment, following your advices, I was able to perform the animation between two controllers but in the `animateTransition` I have to manually add each subviews... is this the right way to go? Using custom transition with a standard Modal Controller the "to-view" is added to the context view automatically... so I wonder if my code is correct.

Comment: I'm glad i could help you :) When you're implementing your own container, you are also responsible for making sure the views of childViewControllers are added and removed properly. Typically, there is only 1 childController's view visible at a time, but thats NOT a must. So when you're currently adding and removing every childViewController's view, your code is probably right ;) System transition (like NavigationController, Modal, etc.) handle the removing of the "fromVC" for you when using custom transitions. I'll put together a bit of example code for you as soon as possible :)

Comment: Thank you Cabus! It is really difficult to find good example about this topic (I mean custom container + custom transition :) ).

Comment: @Cabus I just want to jump in and say I'd love to see this example too!

Comment: Ok finally i got some time to set up an example for you. It is well documented so i guess it will be self explaining :) See https://github.com/ImJCabus/iOS7-Custom-ContainerViewController

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it says so but you are incomplete:

> The UIViewControllerContextTransitioning protocol can be adopted by
>   custom container controllers.  It is purposely general to cover
>   more complex transitions than the system currently supports. For
>   now, navigation push/pops and UIViewController present/dismiss
>   transitions can be customized.

That means you can trigger your VC's `transitioningDelegate` by calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method or you can implement `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:` in your `UINavigationControllerDelegate` class and return an object that conforms `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol.

To sum up, there are only two ways to provide custom transition. Both requires presenting/pushing a VC while we add subviews to create custom container view controllers.

Probably, Apple will do what they said in the first lines of their statement in header file in the future, but for now what you want to do seems impossible.

Comment: I happy to say you were wrong :) check Cabus answer.

Comment: I'd like to give +50 to who deserved it but I can't, when I want to start a bounty it only allows me to give +100. Any help?

Comment: I really don't know if the max limit is 100 or more... I can start more than 100 points bounty too.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning) `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`

> Do not adopt this protocol in your own classes, nor should you
>   directly create objects that adopt this protocol.

Answer (score -2):

Please look at  [MPFoldTransition](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition), it worked for me.

You can also use the following Category, you can create your own transition using this.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Animation)

- (void) moveTo:(CGPoint)destination duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) downUnder:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) removeWithZoomOutAnimation:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) addSubviewWithFadeAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option;
- (void) removeWithSinkAnimation:(int)steps;
- (void) removeWithSinkAnimationRotateTimer:(NSTimer*) timer;

@end
```

Implementation :

```
#import "UIView+Animation.h"

@implementation UIView (Animation)

- (void) moveTo:(CGPoint)destination duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(destination.x,destination.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}

- (void) downUnder:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
         animations:^{
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI);
             self.alpha = self.alpha - 0.5;
         }
         completion:nil];
}

- (void) addSubviewWithZoomInAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    // first reduce the view to 1/100th of its original dimension
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);
    view.transform = trans; // do it instantly, no animation
    [self addSubview:view];
    // now return the view to normal dimension, animating this tranformation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
        animations:^{
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, 100.0, 100.0);
        }
        completion:nil];    
}

- (void) removeWithZoomOutAnimation:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
    animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 0.1, 0.1);
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
        [self removeFromSuperview]; 
    }];
}

// add with a fade-in effect
- (void) addSubviewWithFadeAnimation:(UIView*)view duration:(float)secs option:(UIViewAnimationOptions)option
{
    view.alpha = 0.0;   // make the view transparent
    [self addSubview:view]; // add it
    [UIView animateWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 options:option
                     animations:^{view.alpha = 1.0;}
                     completion:nil];   // animate the return to visible 
}

// remove self making it "drain" from the sink!
- (void) removeWithSinkAnimation:(int)steps
{
    //NSTimer *timer;
    if (steps > 0 && steps < 100)   // just to avoid too much steps
        self.tag = steps;
    else
        self.tag = 50;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(removeWithSinkAnimationRotateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void) removeWithSinkAnimationRotateTimer:(NSTimer*) timer
{
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 0.9, 0.9),0.314);
    self.transform = trans;
    self.alpha = self.alpha * 0.98;
    self.tag = self.tag - 1;
    if (self.tag <= 0)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

@end
```

I hope it solves your problem. enjoy.:)

Comment: You didn't understand my question. My problem is "How to use CUSTOM CONTAINER with CUSTOM TRANSITIONS".